# Android Canvas draw underlined text

Tags: android, canvas, text, draw

How can I draw underlined text to a canvas with Android?
I know how Bold and Italic work, but how would I draw text, which is underlined?
Is it even possible, or do I have to find a workaround to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Paint. UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG),

Ex :

```
class SampleView extends View {
        public SampleView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setTextSize(25);
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);

            paint.setFlags(Paint. UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
            paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            canvas.drawText("My Underline Text", 50, 140, paint);

        }
    }
```

Comment: He is after underline not strike through

Answer (score 2):

On the paint object, set the flag to underline text

```
 paint.setFlags(Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```